# Code transfer between different git repositories

Tags: git

I have a similar codebase developed in two separate repository. The initial version of the codebase is uploaded to github. Then later another repository is created at bitbucket and rest of the local updates pushed into the bitbucket repository. Now I want to do the following:

1. Create a new branch at GitHub.
2. Push the updates from the bitbucket repository into the new branch at Github.

Initially I changed the remote url to push the updates. After the add and commit command , I tried to push , but it did not work . And Now I have the following error:

```
error: commit is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Any hint resolve the conflict and resolve the issue?

Thanks

The following is done after the initial hint:

1. git merge --abort.
2. git add *.h
3. git add *.cpp
4. git commit -m "Rep update"
5. git push origin branch-name

And then I got the following error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: You've attempted a merge (either explicitly with `git merge`, or implicitly, e.g. by `git pull`). Try if `git merge --abort` gets things cleaned up. **Warning:** Doing so, you might loose uncommitted changes.

Comment: Are you trying to push to a new or to an existing remote branch?

Comment: Initially there is a remote master. Then I created another remote branch from remote master. I wanted to push to the new remote branch that I created from remote master.

Comment: What's the output of `git branch -avv`?